# sending array of files from vscode RestClient

Tags: visual-studio-code, multipartform-data

I'm using [RestClient](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) on vsCode for testing my API and [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for saving files in the backend .

I want to know are there any way to send array of files called productImages from a
[RestClient](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client)'s POST request

Answer (score 1):

In order to accept array of files you have to use `multer().array("productImages")` middleware in your route and then `multer` will add all the form-data that has same field `name` to an array of files and you can access the array from `req.files`.

Following is the restClient post request for upload 2 files: -

```
    post http://localhost:4225/add-product-images
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
    
    ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="productImages"; filename="1.png" 
    Content-Type: image/png
    
    < ../files/1.png
    
    ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="productImages"; filename="2.png" 
    Content-Type: image/png
    
    < ../files/2.png
    ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```